# I am learning API testing using Postman, do I also need to know Web services testing?

Tags: api-testing, rest-api, postman, web-service

I am learning API testing using Postman, do I also need to know Web services testing?

I know that we can use JSON, XML, and other formats to transfer data to an API, but we can only use XML format in Web services.

Should I learn Web services testing or Just API testing using Postman enough for the job/interview point of view?

Comment: It really depends on the job you apply. If they want you to test REST APIs, then you need to learn REST API, if they want you to learn RMI API testing, then learn RMI API testing. BTW, API are not always Web services (i.e. API available over the WEB).

Answer (score 1):

While API testing and web services testing are related, they are not the same thing.

API testing refers to testing the application programming interface (API) of an application to ensure that it meets functional and non-functional requirements. This can be done using various tools, including Postman, which is a popular tool for API testing. Postman allows you to test RESTful APIs, which use JSON or XML formats to transfer data.

On the other hand, web services testing involves testing the web services layer of an application, which is responsible for providing access to application functionality over the web. Web services can use various data transfer formats, including JSON and XML, but they are not limited to using only XML.

In terms of job and interview requirements, it depends on the specific job and company you are applying to. Some companies may require knowledge of both API testing and web services testing, while others may only require knowledge of one or the other. It is always beneficial to have knowledge of both, as it increases your overall understanding of how applications and systems work together.

That being said, if you are currently learning API testing using Postman, it is a great place to start. Once you have a good understanding of API testing, you can expand your knowledge to include web services testing if it is necessary for your job or desired for your career growth.